# ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I just installed matplotlib and am trying to run one of there example scripts. However I run into the error detailed below. What am I doing wrong?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 16, extend3d=True)
ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)

plt.show()
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 245, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 945, in gca
    return self.add_subplot(111, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 677, in add_subplot
    projection_class = get_projection_class(projection)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\projections\__init__.py", line 61, in get_projection_class
    raise ValueError("Unknown projection '%s'" % projection)
ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.devel/8904

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Windows XP, Active state python 2.6.5 matplotlib 1.0.0.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Using from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D will solve the problem

Answer (score 121, accepted):

First off, I think `mplot3D` worked a bit differently in `matplotlib` version `0.99` than it does in the current version of `matplotlib`.

Which version are you using? (Try running: `python -c 'import matplotlib; print matplotlib."__version__")`

I'm guessing you're running version `0.99`, in which case you'll need to either use a slightly different syntax or update to a more recent version of `matplotlib`.

If you're running version `0.99`, try doing this instead of using using the `projection` keyword argument:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D #<-- Note the capitalization! 
fig = plt.figure()

ax = Axes3D(fig) #<-- Note the difference from your original code...

X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 16, extend3d=True)
ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)
plt.show()
```

This should work in `matplotlib` `1.0.x`, as well, not just `0.99`.

Comment: I'm running version 0.99.3. I tried your script but it keeps telling me axes3d isn't defined.

Comment: @Anteater - Sorry, I didn't notice that you were using `axes3d`'s test data.  It should be fixed now... That'll teach me to put code in without trying to run it!

Comment: @dashesy - You'll still need to import the 3d projections: `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`. Afterwards, it should work.

Comment: aha, interesting! saw it in the examples but guessed it is for older versions only. Thanks

Comment: what about python 3.6?

Comment: command for print version for python 3 is `python -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)'`

Comment: what about version `2.0.2`?

Comment: I have this error for python 2.7, matplotlib.__version__ '2.2.3' ..... BECAUSE I was not using `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`... :)

Answer (score 70):

Just to add to Joe Kington's answer (not enough reputation for a comment) there is a good example of mixing 2d and 3d plots in the documentation at http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/mixed_subplots_demo.html which shows projection='3d' working in combination with the Axes3D import.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
...
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
...
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, projection='3d')
```

In fact as long as the Axes3D import is present the line

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
...
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```

as used by the OP also works. (checked with matplotlib version 1.3.1)

Comment: This is actually really helpful to know! While the Axes3D import is never explicitly used it enables projection='3d' to be used without error

Comment: The import statement made it work for me. But I can't help feel icky by running this code... Using a import statement to bootstrap some code that looks totally separated on the surface seems like a bad design

Comment: `ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')` does work for me. Instead of `ax = plt.subplot(111,projection="3d")`. I'm using the version of `2.1.0`

Comment: @Ezbob the whole matplotlib API is just a pain in the ass. I always have to google if I want to create even a basic plot. No other python lib has such a crappy API

Answer (score 14):

Import mplot3d whole to use "projection = '3d'".

Insert the command below in top of your script. It should run fine.

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
```

Answer (score 4):

I encounter the same problem, and @Joe Kington and @bvanlew's answer solve my problem.

but I should add more infomation when you use pycharm and enable `auto import`.

when you format the code, the code `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D` will auto remove by pycharm.

so, my solution is

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
Axes3D = Axes3D  # pycharm auto import
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

and it works well!

Comment: You can also put `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` before the import.

Answer (score 2):

As recommended in other comments I found that importing "axes3d" resolved the issue:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

It seems that this is needed if using an older version of matplotlib.pyplot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16,12.5))
ax=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1,projection="3d")

a=ax.scatter(Dataframe['bedrooms'],Dataframe['bathrooms'],Dataframe['floors'])
plt.plot(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact same error but from a different part of the sample script. As such is not totally relevant to the OPs problem but others with this error message in the scripts may find this useful.

Somewhere in the code there were lines -

```
points = points.to_crs({"init": "EPSG:3857"})
```

and

```
city = city.to_crs({"init": "EPSG:3857"})
```

Which generates a warning:

```
FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method.
```

I don't think you can ignore that warning.
The updated syntax is detailed here:

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html#setting-a-projection

Once you change those to

```
points = points.to_crs("EPSG:3857")
```

and

```
city = city.to_crs("EPSG:3857")
```

..the ValueError further down the code goes away.