# Plotting points in 3d from text file using Matplotlib or Octave

Tags: matplotlib, octave

Hi I have a text file containing three columns of numbers; one column each for the x,y,z coordinates of a bunch of points. All numbers are between 0 ad 1.

I want to plot all these points in the unit cube [0,1]x[0,1]x[0,1].

Please let me know how I can do this in Octave or MatPlot lib, whichever prduces a better quality image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is how it looks in Matplotlib:

[image: 3D scatter plot]

This is the code to produce this plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(101)
x,y,z = np.random.rand(3,20)

fig = plt.figure()
# version 1.0.x syntax:
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# version 0.99.x syntax: (accepted by 1.0.x as well)
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.scatter(x,y,z)

fig.savefig('scatter3d.png')
```

As the code suggests, there are slight differences in how matplotlib version 0.99.1.1 and version 1.0.1 behave, as noted in this [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810865/need-help-with-matplotlib/3812324#3812324). I am using 0.99.1.1, and I had trouble using all the options available to 2D `scatter` plots, which should be the same for 3D plots as well. The full list of scatter features are listed [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter).

The above code resulted from looking at the matplotlib [tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.scatter) on 3D plotting.