# Accounting for errors when creating a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, histogram, histogram2d

I have a set of `N` observations distributed as `(x[i], y[i]), i=0..N` points in a 2D space. Each point has associated errors in both coordinates (`e_x[i], e_y[i], i=0..N`) and also a weight attached to it (`w[i], i=0..N`).

I'd like to generate a 2D histogram of these `N` points, accounting not only for the weights but also for the errors, which would cause each point to be *spread* possibly among many bins if the error values are large enough (assuming a standard [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) for the errors, although other distributions could perhaps be considered).

I see that [numpy.histogram2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) has a `weights` parameter so that is taken care of. The issue would be how to account for the errors in each of the `N` observed points.

Is there a function that would let me do this? I'm open to anything in `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: What do these error values represent? Are these standard deviations along the principal axes?

Comment: Ok, that set of parameters constitutes a multivariate GMM, with given weights (\pi_i), the samples as means (\mu_i) and covariance matrices (\Sigma_i) given by [[e_x[i]**2,0][0,e_y[i]**2]]. Unlike the standard normal case you assumed (which corresponds to all e_x and e_y being equal to 1.0), you have covariance matrices where the diagonal can have distinct values. This corresponds to ellipses with major axes along the principal axes, as opposed to circles. Does that help you moving forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon user1415946's comment, you can assume each point represents a [bi-variate normal distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) with the covariance matrices given by `[[e_x[i]**2,0][0,e_y[i]**2]]`. However, the resulting distribution is not a normal distribution - you'll see, after running the example, how the histogram doesn't resemble a Gaussian at all, but instead a group of them.

To create a histogram out of this set of distributions, one way I see is by generating random samples out of each point using [numpy.random.multivariate_normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html). See the example code below with some artificial data.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# This is a function I like to use for plotting histograms
def plotHistogram3d(hist, xedges, yedges):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    hist = hist.transpose()
    # Transposing is done so that bar3d x and y match hist shape correctly
    dx = np.mean(np.diff(xedges))
    dy = np.mean(np.diff(yedges))

    # Computing the number of elements
    elements = (len(xedges) - 1) * (len(yedges) - 1)
    # Generating mesh grids.
    xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+dx/2.0, yedges[:-1]+dy/2.0)

    # Vectorizing matrices
    xpos = xpos.flatten()
    ypos = ypos.flatten()
    zpos = np.zeros(elements)
    dx = dx * np.ones_like(zpos) * 0.5  # 0.5 factor to give room between bars.
# Use 1.0 if you want all bars 'glued' to each other
    dy = dy * np.ones_like(zpos) * 0.5
    dz = hist.flatten()

    ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Count')
    return

"""
INPUT DATA
"""
#                 x  y ex ey  w
data = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
                 [3, 0, 1, 1, 2],
                 [0, 1, 2, 1, 5],
                 [7, 7, 1, 3, 1]])

"""
Generate samples
"""
# Sample size (100 samples will be generated for each data point)
SAMPLE_SIZE = 100
# I want to fill in a table with columns [x, y, w]. Each data point generates SAMPLE_SIZE
# samples, so we have SAMPLE_SIZE * (number of data points) generated points
points = np.zeros((SAMPLE_SIZE * data.shape[0], 3))  # Initializing this matrix

for i, element in enumerate(data):  # For each row in the data set
    meanVector = element[:2]
    covarianceMatrix = np.diag(element[2:4]**2)  # Diagonal matrix with elements equal to error^2
    # For columns 0 and 1, add generated x and y samples
    points[SAMPLE_SIZE*i:SAMPLE_SIZE*(i+1), :2] = \
        np.random.multivariate_normal(meanVector, covarianceMatrix, SAMPLE_SIZE)
    # For column 2, simply copy original weight
    points[SAMPLE_SIZE*i:SAMPLE_SIZE*(i+1), 2] = element[4]  # weights

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], weights=points[:, 2])
plotHistogram3d(hist, xedges, yedges)
plt.show()
```

Results plotted below:

[image]

Comment: Gabriel, could you add some comments describing what each lines does in your example? Also, which version of `matplotlib` are you running? I have version 1.3.1 and trying to run your example gives me a `ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'`; this is odd since the example given here http://stackoverflow.com/q/3810865/1391441 does work with no issues.

Comment: I use the same version as yours, but I had mistakenly remove an import line prior to answering. This one should work. Thanks