# How to plot polyline in 3D in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, polyline

I have sequence of point with 3 coordinates each

How to plot them as polyline in 3D?

The following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 3, 4]
z = [5, 6, 7]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```

throws

```
Unknown projection '3d'
```

Comment: Related? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810865/matplotlib-unknown-projection-3d-error

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil is there unified way to plot in python? Why should one follow 10 different procedures for each type of task?

Comment: @Dims The procedure is always the same, read the docs and do as they say.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an import statement. Add `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`
 and you should be fine.