# ValueError: Unknown projection '3d' (once again)

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda, spyder, matplotlib-3d

When executing this line of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#your code

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```

I have an output error:

```
raise ValueError("Unknown projection %r" % projection)

ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

The error appears also when I use Spyder as IDE.
The version of `matplotlib` is

```
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
matplotlib: 1.5.0rc3
```

But I had the same problem even with other versions of `matplotlib`.
A similar error was reported in [this question (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810865/matplotlib-unknown-projection-3d-error) but the answers do not help. Some suggestions on how to modify the instruction?
matplotlib: 3.0.2

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You will have to import `Axes3D` to enable the 3d plotting in matplotlib. The official tutorials on 3d plotting can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html). So the correct imports and code would look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # <--- This is important for 3d plotting 

#your code

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```